# How to prove the 1-norm of a sequence of $L^1$ functions does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I've been learning Lebesgue Integral recently and the following is a problem in one of our previous sample exams:

> If {$f_n$} is a bounded sequence of functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $f_n\to f$ a.e. and
> suppose that for any $M>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]}|f_N|>1$$ Prove that $||f_n||_1$ does NOT converge to $||f||_1$.

I tried to separate the integral $||f_n||_1$ into two parts: $[-M,M]$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]$. The first part converges due to the Bounded Convergence Theorem. So it suffices to prove the second part does NOT converge. But I don't know where to go from there.

I also thought of functions, e.g. $\chi_{[-n-1,-n]\cup[n,n+1]}$ that satisfy the given conditions but had no idea how to use the properties of those functions. Any hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: The following should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83208/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-l1-norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, we can notice, as pointed out by PhoemueX, that [if $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere and $\lVert f_n\rVert_1\to\lVert f\rVert_1$, then $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_1\to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/if-f-k-to-f-a-e-and-the-lp-norms-converge-then-f-k-to-f-in-lp). Consequently, it suffices to prove that we do not have $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_1\to 0$.
- To do so, it suffices to find a increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that $\lVert f_{n_k}-f\rVert_1\geqslant 1/2$ for each $k$.
- Let us construct this sequence. Fatou's lemma combined with boundedness in $L^1$ of $(f_n)$ imply that $f$ is integrable. As a consequence, there exists $M_1$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_1,M_1]}\lvert f\rvert\leqslant 1/2$.
- Let $n_1$ be such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_1,M_1]}\lvert f_{n_1}\rvert\gt 1$. Then  $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_1,M_1]}\lvert f_{n_1}-f\rvert\geqslant 1/2$.
- Suppose now that $n_1<\dots<n_k$ and $M_1<\dots<M_k$ are such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_i,M_i]}\lvert f_{n_i}-f\rvert\geqslant 1/2$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. Let us find $M_{k+1}>M_k$ and $n_{k+1}>n_k$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_{k+1},M_{k+1}]}\lvert f_{n_{k+1}}-f\rvert\geqslant 1/2$. Pick $M_{k+1}>M_k$ such that for each $\ell\in\{1,\dots,n_k\}$,
  $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_{k+1},M_{k+1}]}\lvert f_\ell\rvert\leqslant 1$.  Applying the assumption with $M=M_{k+1}$, we can find $N$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_{k+1},M_{k+1}]}\lvert f_N\rvert\gt 1$ and by construction, this $N$ is necessarily bigger than $n_k$, hence $n_{k+1}=N$ does the job.
- We thus found sequences $(M_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ and $(n_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ for which the inequality $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_k,M_k]}\lvert f_{n_k}-f\rvert\geqslant 1/2$ holds for each $k$. Then
  $$
  \int_{\mathbb R}\lvert f_{n_k}-f\rvert\geqslant \int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M_k,M_k]}\lvert f_{n_k}-f\rvert\geqslant 1/2
  $$
  allows to conclude.

Comment: Nice argument! Just a small typo: It should read $\|f_n-f\|_1\rightarrow 0$ in the first bullet.

Comment: @Matija Thanks! This is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're considering the complete Lebesgue measure, i.e. subsets of null sets are measurable. We prove the following claim.

**Claim:** Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, and for $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be measurable, with the following properties. We have $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<  \infty$, we have $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ almost everywhere, and for each $M\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}|f_n(x)|\mathrm dx>1$. Then we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1\neq\|f\|_1$, should the left hand side be well-defined.

First, let's get rid of some technical obstacles. For this purpose replace $f$ in the claim with $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and $f_n$ by $g_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ to obtain the claim for *non-negative* functions. If the claim holds, then so does the claim for non-negative functions since this is a special case. If the claim does not hold, then there exist $f$, $f_n$ with all properties and such that $\|f\|_1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1$. Set $g(x)=|f(x)|$, $g_n(x)=|f_n(x)|$, notice that $g_n(x)\rightarrow g(x)$ a.e. and that the other properties as well as $\|g\|_1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|g_n\|_1$ trivially hold, so the claim for non-negative functions also does not hold. This shows that the two claims are equivalent, and we may hence restrict to non-negative functions.

Next, notice that $f$ being an a.e. pointwise limit of measurable functions is itself [measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1095723/1096797). Let $\mathcal E$ be a measurable set such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for $x\in\mathcal E$ and such that $\mathbb R\setminus\mathcal E$ is a null set. Let $g_n(x)=f_n(x)$, $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in\mathcal E$, and $g_n(x)=g(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $g_n$, $g$ are [measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427206/almost-everywhere-equal-implies-measurable). Clearly, the claim and the claim with $f_n$, $f$ replaced by $g_n$, $g$ are equivalent, so we may also assume that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ (not only a.e.).

Let $f_n$ have the desired properties. Now, we extract an increasing injection $\nu:\mathbb Z_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]}g_n(x)\mathrm dx>1$, where $g_n=f_{\nu(n)}$, as follows. For given $M$ let $N(M)$ be such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}f_{N(M)}(x)\mathrm dx>1$.
Using $\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ and $f_n\ge 0$, let $M(n)$ be such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M(n),M(n)]}f_n(x)\mathrm dx<1$.
Let $\nu(1)=N(1)$. For $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $M=\max\{M(n):n\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\nu(n)]\}\cup\{n+1\}$ and $\nu(n+1)=N(M)$. Notice that $\nu(n+1)>\nu(n)$ because $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}f_n(x)\mathrm dx<1$ for all $n\le\nu(n)$ (since $M\ge M(n)$) and that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-(n+1),n+1]}f_{\nu(n+1)}(x)\mathrm dx>1$ since $M\ge n+1$. Hence, the sequence $\{g_n\}$ has the desired properties. Now, it is straightforward to check that the original claim and the following claim are equivalent.

**Claim:** For $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ be measurable, with the following properties. The (measurable) pointwise limit $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, $x\mapsto\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$, exists, we have $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ for all $n$, and we have $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]}|f_n(x)|\mathrm dx>1$ for all $n$. Then we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1\neq\|f\|_1$, if the left hand side is well-defined.

Let $f_n$ have the desired properties. First, notice that by [Fatou's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) we have $\|f\|_1\le\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ (considering the restriction to the Borel algebra of the completion of the Borel algebra does no harm here, since the domains can be any measure spaces). So, let $M$ be sufficiently large such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}f(x)\mathrm dx\le 1$. Further, let $g=\chi_{[-M,M]}f$ and $g_n=\chi_{[-M,M]}f_n$, then $g_n$ converges pointwise to $g$ and Fatou's Lemma yields $\|g\|_1\le\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|g_n\|_1$, which further gives $\|f\|_1<\|g\|_1+1\le\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|g_n\|_1+1\le\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1$. Thus, we have even established the following, stronger result.

**Corollary:** For $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ be measurable, with the following properties. The (measurable) pointwise limit $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, $x\mapsto\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$, exists, we have $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ for all $n$, and we have $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]}|f_n(x)|\mathrm dx>1$ for all $n$. Then we have $\|f\|_1<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1$.

As clarified in the comments, the assumption $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ is crucial. Otherwise, we may consider $f_n=\chi_{[-(n+1),n+1]}$ and $f\equiv 1$, yielding $\|f\|_1=\infty=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1$. On the other hand, notice that we may even have $\|f_n\|_1=\infty$ for infintely many $n$, as long as pointwise convergence is preserved and we have $\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ for infintely many $n$. An example would be $f_{2n}=f+\chi_{\mathbb R\setminus[-2n,2n]}$, $f_{2n+1}=f+\chi_{[2n+1,2n+2]}+\chi_{[-2n-2,-2n-1]}$.

Comment: In the second line of your answer, how do you know those $k$'s are different? In other words, for different $M$, why can't those $N$'s be the same?

Comment: To answer the second question, let $A$ be the bound from the answer. Fix $M_0$ and corresponding $N_0$. Since we have $\|f_N\|_1\le A$ for all $N$, we know that $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}|f_N(x)\mathrm dx=0$. Hence, there exists $M(N)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M(N),M(N)]}|f_N(x)\mathrm dx<1$. Let $M=\max\{M(N):N\le N_0\}$. Then we have $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}|f_N(x)\mathrm dx<1$ for all $N\le N_0$. So, for the $N$ corresponding to $M$ we necessarily have $N>N_0$. So, no matter how large we choose $M$, we find infinitely many suitable $N$.

Comment: It is true that all $f_N$'s are all $L^1$ integrable. But why is there a common bound $A$ for all of them?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the bound $A=A(N)$ may depend on $N$, but this doesn't change the argument above (since $M(N)$ also depends on $N$). However, it does change the last part of the answer, i.e. $\|f\|_1=\infty$. This raises the question: Do we assume that $f$ is integrable? Or does $\|f_n\|_1\rightarrow\infty=\|f\|_1$ not count as convergence? Because you could take $f_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}$ and $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: Yep you are right. I guess it now goes to what "bounded" means in this problem. If it only refers to absolute value, then the problem is wrong. But if it refers to the $L^1$ integration, then $f_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}$ is not bounded in that sense. So let's assume it refers to the latter.

Comment: Ok, I assumed less than the latter and updated the answer. I took the liberty to simplify the claim even further and only consider non-negative functions with a pointwise limit and the simplified tail property as discussed here in the comments. This allows to apply Fatou's lemma. Notice that the initial question is of interest in its own right since the assumptions differ. So, I'll add another answer for the other assumptions.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for spending time answering my question! Then I'd like to apologize that I'm not good enough to understand your answer completely right away. But trust me, I'll try my best to understand it and give you feedback within the next two days.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have trouble understanding specific steps, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

If the claim is false, then [$f_n$ converges in $L^1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605967/how-to-prove-the-1-norm-of-a-sequence-of-l1-functions-does-not-converge) That is,

$\int_{\mathbb R}|f_n-f|\to 0.$

For each integer $M$, there is an integer $n(M)$ such that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]}|f_{n(M)}|>1.$

Then,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]}|f|+\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]}|f_{n(M)}-f|>1$

and so in fact,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-M,M]}|f|+\int_{\mathbb R}|f_{n(M)}-f|>1.$

But $f$ is $L^1$ (why?) so if we can choose a subsequence of integers, $(M_k)_k$ such that $n(M_{k+1})>n(M_k)$ if we then let $k\to \infty,$ we will have a contradiction.

So, suppose we have chosen the first $k$ elements in such a way that $n(M_j)>n(M_{j-1}):\ 1\le j\le k.$ Since the $f_n$ are integrable, there is an integer $M'$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M',M]}|f_m|<\frac{1}{2}$ for $1\le m\le n(M_k).$ But by hypothesis, for this $M'$, there is a $f_{n(M')}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-M',M]}|f_{n(M')}|>1.$ We may take $M'>M_k.$ (why?). Then, $n(M')>n(M_k)$ so setting $M_{k+1}=M'$ completes the induction, and the proof.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in my other answer, we may restrict to sequences $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ of measurable functions such that the pointwise limit $f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ exists (with $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$), and such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]}f_n(x)\mathrm dx>1$.
Now, we replace the assumption $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ by the following assumption.

**Claim:** Let $f_n$ be as described above, and further assume that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_\infty<\infty$. Then we have $\|f\|_1=\infty$ or $\|f\|_1<\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_1$.

For $\|f\|_1=\infty$ we are done, so let $\|f\|_1<\infty$. Then there exists $M$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-M,M]}f(x)\mathrm dx<1$. Also, there exists a subsequence $g_n$ of $f_n$ with $\|g_n\|<B$ for all $n$, where $B=2\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_\infty$ (obtained from the minimizing sequence for the limes inferior). Clearly, we still have $g_n\rightarrow f$ and $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]}g_n(x)\mathrm dx>1$ (since $g_n=f_N$ for some $N\ge n$). Now, the [Bounded Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/explanation-of-the-bounded-convergence-theorem) shows that $\|h_n\|_1\rightarrow\|h\|_1$ for $h_n=\chi_{[-M,M]}g_n$ and $h=\chi_{[-M,M]}f$. But this gives $\|f\|_1<\|h\|_1+1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|h_n\|_1+1\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|g_n\|_1$.

As discussed in the comments and the previous answer, the case $\|f\|_1=\infty$ is relevant since we may take $\chi_{[-n,n]}$. But if $\|f\|_1$ is finite, it is strictly lower than the limes inferior. As for the other answer, notice that we may even have $\|f_n\|_\infty=\infty$ for infinitely many $n$, and in particular we do not need uniform bounds (in $n$) for $\|f_n\|_\infty$. Also notice that the two results do not imply each other. The result in the other answer allows for the sequence $f_n=f+n\chi_{[-1/n,1/n]}+\chi_{[n,n+2]}$ which violates the assumptions here. Conversely, here we may consider $f_n=f+\chi_{[n,\infty)}$ (using that $\|f\|_\infty\le\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_\infty<\infty$) which violates the assumptions of the result in the other answer.