# Counter-examples for almost everywhere equal stochastic processes that have different measurability

Tags: stochastic-processes, measurable-functions

$(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is our sample space. Consider two stochastic processes $X,Y$ that are almost everywhere equal (i.e., $\forall t, \mathbb{P}(X_t)=\mathbb{P}(Y_t)$ a.s.). Suppose that $X_t$ is adapted to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, how to construct a counter-example in which $Y_t$ is not adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$?

This problem is from this Annals-24 [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13559), which in pg.5 last paragraph states that "(the intensity process of a counting process) $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ is not a prior $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted but has a $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted version".

I have discussed this with the author, but he cannot give a complete counter-example, either. I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427206/almost-everywhere-equal-implies-measurable) post, but I (and the author of the paper) thought things might be different for stochastic process?

---

NOTE:
for anyone who is new to measure theory (like myself), I explain the answer by @geetha290krm in detail.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, with $\mathcal{F}$ the Lebesgure $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathbb{P}$ the Lebesgure measure on [0,1]. Let $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Recall that

> $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set if there is a Borel measurable set $B$ and a Lebesgue measure zero set $N$ s.t. $A=B\triangle N:=(B\backslash N)\cup(N\backslash B)$

Now, consider a Lebesgue measurable set $A$ (that is not Borel measurable). Let $B$, $N$ the corresponding two sets in the above definition. Let $X:=1_B, Y:=1_A$.

We can see that $\mathbb{P}(X\neq Y)=\mathbb{P}(N)=0$. Meanwhile, we have $X$ a Borel measurable function because $B$ is a Borel set, and $Y$ not Borel measurable because $A$ is not a Borel set. This means $X$ being measurable to $\mathcal{B}$ and $X=Y$ a.e. does not imply $Y$ being measurable to $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy: Let $\Omega=(0,1), \mathcal F$ the $\sigma-$algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, $\mathcal G$  the $\sigma-$algebra of  Borel sets; Let $A$ be a  Lebesgue measurable set which is not a Borel set, $Y_t=1_A$ for all $t$. There is a Borel set $B$ such that $A\Delta B$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Let $X_t=1_B$ for every $t$. Let $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal G$ for every $t$.

Comment: Borel $\sigma-$ algebra is not complete under Lebesgure measure. If you have a complete $\sigma-$ algebra then any function almost everywhere equal to a measurable function would also be measurable but that does not apply here. @MingzhouLiu

Comment: I see. This explains [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427206/almost-everywhere-equal-implies-measurable) post.